# Auto-sync is turning itself on randomly

Tags: sync, 7.0-nougat, nexus-6

(Nexus 6 on rooted stock Android 7.1.1)

I have a feeling a rogue app is turning on auto-sync, but is there any way to discover which one?

I checked that it was switched it off this morning and at some point in the last 4 hours, it has come back on without me doing anything.

Comment: and how did you discover it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rogue app that was switching on auto-sync was Kana Town 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.koridev.kanatown

Comment: and how did you discover it?

Comment: That was 2 years ago, but it may have either been through process of elimination or possibly checking the app ops settings.

Comment: @Rules any way to find?